# Neo4j: Listing node labels

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 2 hierarchies in my database.

Hierarchy 1:

Company{name:'ABC', CompanyId:1,} <-- Category <-- SubCategory <-- Service <-- Asset <-- Anomaly

Hierarchy 2:

Company{name:'XYZ', CompanyId:21,} <-- Category <-- Service <-- Asset <-- Anomaly

What is the best way to query node labels in my hierarchy for a CompanyId? I am looking for an output in the following format:

CompanyId:1

Company
Category
SubCategory
Service
Anomaly

CompanyId:2

Company
Category
Service
Anomaly

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that every company hierarchy chain begins with a company node that has the label `Company` and always and with an node with the `Anomaly` label, you could go after paths of the company hierarchy and return the list of labels for each chain.

```
match p=(:Company)<-[*]-(:Anomaly)
with head(nodes(p)) as Company, p
return Company.CompanyId, reduce(labels = "", n IN nodes(p) | labels + labels(n)[0] + " ")
```

Comment: Using the above query, getting the following error - Type mismatch: expected Collection<T> but was Path (line 2, column 11) "with head(p) as Company, p".

Comment: sorry about that, i was a little hasty with that.  The `p` is a path but `head` expects a collection.  `nodes(p)` returns a collection.